# Prevent update of all components on button click

Tags: reactjs, components

I have an array of objects and displayed them using map. A '+' button associated with each component. I want to update the count of a specific component on button click. I tried with the following code. However, it is updating the count of all the other components also. What can I do to fix this?

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { people } from './Data.js';

function App() {
  const[count,setCount]=useState(0)
  const updateCount=()=>{
    setCount(count+1)
  }
  return (
  <div>
    <h4>List of Items</h4>
    {
      people.map((item)=>{

        return (
        <div key={item.id}>count:{count}
        <button onClick={()=>updateCount}>+</button>
        </div>
        )
        })
    }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't see how `()=>updateCount` would update *anything*, since it doesn't actually invoke a function.  Aside from that... You only have *one* `count` value.  How are you expecting a single integer to track multiple values?  Did you mean to have an *array* of integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage the state individually.  Here's a possible alternative, hope it helps.

```js
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { people } from './Data.js';

function PeopleItem(props) {
const[count,setCount]=useState(0)
const updateCount=()=>setCount(count+1)
const {item} = props
return <div>count:{count}
      <button onClick={updateCount}>+</button>
  </div>
}


export function App() {
return (
<div>
  <h4>List of Items</h4>
  {
    people.map((item)=> <PeopleItem key={item.id} item={item}/>)
  }
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update count on a single component you need to initialize the useState inside the child component. Extract the map and create a component for the return statement. Consider the following:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { people } from './Data.js';

function ChildComponent(props){
    const[count,setCount]=useState(0)
    
    const updateCount=() => {
      setCount(prev => prev + 1)
    }
    
    return (<div>
                  count:{count}
                 <button onClick={()=>updateCount()}>+</button>
           </div>)

}

function App() {
  
    return (
        <div>
          <h4>List of Items</h4>
           {
            people.map((item)=>{

                 return (
                  <ChildComponent key={item.id}/>
                  )
             })
            }
           </div>
           );
      }

export default App;
```